# Stability - Which is the characteristic equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the system $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x+y\sin (xy), \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-2y+x\sin (xy), \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=-2x$$

I have to show that the equilibrium point is asymptotically stable.

$$$$

The non-homogeneous term $g=(y\sin (xy), x\sin (xy))$ doesn't satisfy the condition $\frac{\|g\|}{\|\overline{x}\|}\rightarrow 0$ while $x\rightarrow 0$, does it?

So, we take the Taylor expansion at $(0,0)$: $$\sin (xy)=xy-\frac{x^3y^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5y^5}{5!}+\dots $$

So, the system becomes $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x+xy^2+O(x^3y^4), \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-2y+x^2y+O(x^4y^3), \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=-2x$$

So, the system of first approximation is of the form $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x+xy^2, \ \ \frac{dy}{dt}=-2y+x^2y, \ \ \frac{dz}{dt}=-2x$$

How can we find the characteristic equation?

I got sruck because of the terms $xy^2$ and $x^2y$.

Could you give me a hint?

do we maybe look for a lyapunov function?

Comment: Do you know what the Jacobi matrix is?

Comment: It is a matrix of the partial derivatives, right? But which functions do we use this in this case? Of $x$ and $y$ ? @Artem

Comment: Right. If you have your problem $\dot x=f(x,y), \dot y=g(x,y)$, then you use your $f$ and $g$, find the Jacobi matrix, plug the coordinates of the equilibrium, calculate eigenvalues and conclude...

Comment: Ok, I will do that... Thank you!! :-) @Artem